# Centos 6.2 static IP: only getting IPV6 address and need IPV4

Tags: networking, centos, ip

I installed a Centos 6.2 min install. I have edited `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` and I have `ifcfg-eth0,eth1`

I have tried to setup static IPs but I only get IPV6 address back on both adapters and can't ping anything since the rest of the network is IPV4.

I have copied my working settings from another Centos 6 server I have setup and working. Not sure what to do next?

I already added a line to say `NETWORKING_IPV6=no`

Comment: Please post the ifcfg scripts so we can take a look! Is your network manager set to IPV6 (if it's installed)? If network manager is running, it'll override your static settings unless you explicitly say to not manage the interface.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of this in your ifcfg-eth0 file *should* work:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.0.10
TYPE=Ethernet
```

If you're having trouble, posting your network scripts would be helpful.

Comment: I will try that when I get home and let you know thanks. I have edited in and out so many times. Was starting to think problem with 6.2??? Used same settings as my other working server 6.0, and didnt work.

Comment: ok mine is just like your except i have hardware= for network adapter that was already there. I also have a gateway and 2 dns addresses defined. still not working.

Comment: I have tried editing also probmode.conf files as some suggested along with network file. Im at the point of reinstalling with Centos 6.0 instead of 6.2. I have a 6.0 version running fine with static ipv4 no problems.

Comment: Loaded Centos 6.0 network adapters working fine ipv4.